# Struggling with Captcha: Seeking Guidance on Overcoming the Challenge

Tags: base64, captcha

Cancel

how to get the postition of the three shapes inside base64 is there a way to make a javascript that can give me the postion of the three shapes with value start from 1 to 250 i cant find any one on the planet that can solve this